# Filebeat on kubernetes - excluding namespaces doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, filebeat

I have a filebeat outside of the kubernetes cluster, installed as an application on the host. I want to ignore two namespaces in filebeat, since they are very large and I don't need them within elastichsearch.

Here is my input definition in filebeat.yml:

```
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  json.message_key: log
  json.keys_under_root: true
  processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        in_cluster: false
        host: main-backend
        kube_config: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
    - drop_event.when.regexp:
        or:
          - kubernetes.namespace: "kube-system"
          - kubernetes.namespace: "monitoring"
```

However, I still see a lot of log from those namespaces within my elasticsearch. Is there any way to debug it why is it happening?

Comment: For anyone still looking for an answer to this, https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/10393#issuecomment-767032435

Answer (score 2):

Can you try as given below

```
- drop_event:
          when:
            or:
            - not:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: "kube-system"
            - not:
                equals:
                  kubernetes.namespace: "monitoring"
            - regexp:
                kubernetes.pod.name: "filebeat-*"
            - regexp:
                kubernetes.pod.name: "elasticsearch-*"
```

Comment: Seems like it drops everything. No data reach my elastic search.

Comment: @Djent is asking to exclue monitoring and kube-system. I think he need to remove the two "not" before equals, meaning to drop events when namespace is monitoring or kube-system

Comment: how about running filebeat per application? most doc online expect filebeat for the cluster...but what if i want filebeat to ship logs per app deployed inside cluster???

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this snippet in filebeat.yml and it works.
Note that I didn't add the kubernetes_metadata, just the docker_metadata (which contains kubernetes labels, too).

```
#================================ Processors =====================================

# Configure processors to enhance or manipulate events generated by the beat.
#
processors:
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
#  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
  - drop_event:
        when:
          equals:
            container.labels.io_kubernetes_pod_namespace: "kube-system"
          or:
            equals:
              container.labels.io_kubernetes_pod_namespace: "monitoring"
```

In this case logs coming from containers within the "cattle-prometheus" namespace will be dropped.